# Where should one store scripts specific to a view or set of views?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript

It seems counter to good practice to place all JavaScript files in the `~/Scripts' folder. I see massive view specific scripts incorporated into the view, but now with the advent of TypeScript, with its compiled JS files, a developer should decide where these should go.

Comment: in your scripts folder

Comment: I store ts files in a sub directory called ts under Scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide your scripts folder in the same way as your views folder... But I recommend thinking more in terms of either...

For smaller sets of scripts - bundle, minify, serve a single script. Reduction in requests and caching of the script will almost certainly trump trying to serve lots of small scripts. You are welcome to measure and adjust if you think you have something different from the norm.

For larger sets of scripts think of the scripts as a program and organise them that way rather than by tying them to your views. So look to create modules that do specific jobs, rather than serve specific pages.